# How to increase timeouts in Stretcher gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

We're having some problems with timeouts happening a lot in our Stretcher gem for ElasticSearch. This results in many "Faraday::Error::ConnectionFailed·end of file reached (EOFError)" exceptions. It's happening because our Elastic cluster gets slow sometimes.

Adding the timeouts in Stretcher init didn't work. It apparently ignores the values.

```
@server = Stretcher::Server.new('http://localhost:9200', 
{:logger => Rails.logger, :read_timeout => 240, :open_timeout => 30})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the above is actually correct. For some reason it was not picking up the values until a full passenger restart.